# Is it possible to covert an existing multi-module project into a single module project in IntelliJ idea?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, confluence

[Here's the modules my project consist of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8mEC.png)I am working on a relationship plugin project for confluence and my project contains multi- modules and now i want to convert it into a single module project.
Any help would be appreciated.

I have not experimented anything just googling right now if i could find anything relevant.

Comment: You should be able to just merge your source trees.

Comment: Copy all `src` folders into the project root, and add all dependencies and some specific config from sub-modules' pom.xml into the project root's pom.xml. It should not very difficult and back up firstly before converting may help if you have done something wrong later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can merge them to a single module, sure.

The one who created this project got a little eager with the number of modules that are required. Are they necessary or not? That depends on a lot of things.

To merge them, copy the src/main/java and src/main/resources to the top level project, and go through the child pom.xml's to see if there are any properties, dependencies or plugin executions that also need to be moved up.

disable the  tag from the root pom and rename it as you please - check it builds with mvn clean install.

Good luck :)

Comment: Hey vikingsteve, your solution solved my issue thanks for your time and efforts buddy. Was stuck on this since yesterday.

Comment: youre most welcome. good luck onwards